# Can anyone suggest heuristics to take a web page and identify the dominant colors used?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, image-processing, html-parsing

I want to write server-side software, to run on Google App Engine (so it must be pure-Java), that can identify the dominant colors used in a web page, particularly the foreground (text), header, and background colors.

The problem is that the colors used may be specified in CSS, the HTML, or possibly in image files linked to either from the CSS, or the HTML.

One possible approach would be to render the web page to an image, and then do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421863/get-dominant-colors-from-image-discarding-the-background/1421915#1421915), however then I'd need a pure-Java library that can do a reasonable job of rendering a web page to an image.

Another possibility is somehow analyzing the HTML, CSS, and any linked images to extract this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would have to do some image processing to get the colors from the pictures anyway, I would try to take the route of rendering the page and then determining the dominant colors.

As for rendering, it seems like at least webkit is available on Java, so maybe its API have what you need?

Comment: +1 for rendering page to an image. If you went down the route of parsing HTML+CSS+Images, by the time you were finished you would have sucessfully re-invented a web-browser. You might want to consider using an [external service to fetch the screenshot via HTTP](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=web-page+screen+shot+api+service)

Comment: Webkit's written in C - so even if it has a Java interface, it's not pure Java.

Comment: True. There are probably other options. Unless the "pure Java" part is incredibly important I'd probably try to use a renderer that is as mainstream as possible.

Comment: Pure Java is a requirement as it must run on Google App Engine :-/  Using an external service is a possibility...